# "PGError: ERROR: current transaction is aborted" in rails3 migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, transactions, migration, rails-migrations

I'm under Rails 3.0.9, with Ruby 1.9.2 (p290).
Using Postgresql 9.0.4, and the 'pg' gem v0.11.0

The problem is :

I've got a really simple migration just changing the value of a column with conditions :

```
def self.up
  Closet.reset_column_information
  say_with_time "Unifying gender column to h/f" do
    Closet.connection.update "UPDATE closets AS c SET gender='h' WHERE c.gender IN ('homme', 'Homme', 'men', 'Men');"
    Closet.connection.update "UPDATE closets AS c SET gender='f' WHERE c.gender IN ('femme', 'Femme', 'women', 'Women');"
  end
end
```

Every request works perfectly in my erb console and in the pgAdmin SQL's console too,  but when I run the migration it says :

```
PGError: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

If anyone as an idea...

Here is bigger part of the error message stack :

==  MigrateClosets: migrating =================================================
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

```
PGError: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: UPDATE closets SET gender='h' WHERE closets.gender  = 'homme';
/Users/gdurelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@dressmeNG/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:207:in `rescue in log'
/Users/gdurelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@dressmeNG/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:199:in `log'
/Users/gdurelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@dressmeNG/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:514:in `execute'
/Users/gdurelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@dressmeNG/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:288:in `update_sql'
/Users/gdurelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@dressmeNG/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:525:in `update_sql'
/Users/gdurelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@dressmeNG/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:49:in `update'
/Users/gdurelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@dressmeNG/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:16:in `update'
/Users/gdurelle/Sites/rails/DressMeNextGen/db/migrate/20110613125139_migrate_closets.rb:4:in `up'
/Users/gdurelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@dressmeNG/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:314:in `block in migrate'
/Users/gdurelle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `measure'
/Users/gdurelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@dressmeNG/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:314:in `migrate'
```

Comment: There will be an error before this one that caused the transaction to abort.  You need to find that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple wild guesses that might help. Looks like you have a transaction aborting, being caught, and ignored somewhere; that can mess up the entire transaction the `self.up` runs in and that would explain your error message and the behavior you're seeing.

The [`reset_column_information`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-reset_column_information) call usually goes *after* the database change and only if the schema has changed and you need to use the new schema for the rest of the migration; neither of these apply to you so you can drop `Closet.reset_column_information` completely.

You should also have an `execute` method available in your migrations so there's no need to talk to the Closet at all. Also, you don't need semicolons at the end of your SQL statements; they probably won't hurt but if we strip this right down to the bare essentials we might make the problem go away.

Try this and see what happens:

```
def self.up
  say_with_time "Unifying gender column to h/f" do
    execute %q{UPDATE closets SET gender = 'h' WHERE gender IN ('homme', 'Homme', 'men', 'Men')}
    execute %q{UPDATE closets SET gender = 'f' WHERE gender IN ('femme', 'Femme', 'women', 'Women')}
  end
end
```

This gives us the bare minimum that we need to get your database updated. Hopefully the stray transaction problem went away with all the other stuff you didn't need.